# Can UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer Be Merged?

Tags: ios, concatenation, uigesturerecognizer, matrix-multiplication

I am struggling a bit trying to figure out if it is possible to create a single combined gesture recognizer that combines UIPinchGestureRecognizer with UIPanGestureRecognizer.

I am using pan for view translation and pinch for view scaling. I am doing incremental matrix concatenation to derive a resultant final transformation matrix that is applied to the view. This matrix has both scale and translation. Using separate gesture recognizers leads to a jittery movement/scaling. Not what I want. Thus, I want to handle concatenation of scale and translation once within a single gesture. Can someone please shed some light on how to do this?

Comment: Doug, I've updated my answer with complete source code and a sample project.

Answer (score 21):

**6/14/14: Updated Sample Code for iOS 7+ with ARC.**

The UIGestureRecognizers can work together and you just need to make sure you don't trash the current view's transform matrix. Use the CGAffineTransformScale method and related methods that take a transform as input, rather than creating it from scratch (unless you maintain the current rotation, scale, or translation yourself.

### Download Xcode Project

- [Sample UIPinchGesture project on Github](https://github.com/PaulSolt/LimitPinchGestureZoom).

Note: iOS 7 behaves weird with UIView's in IB that have Pan/Pinch/Rotate gestures applied. iOS 8 fixes it, but my workaround is to add all views in code like this code example.

### Demo Video

[image: Demo UIPinchGesture Video]

1. Add them to a view and conform to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol

   ```
   @interface ViewController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

   @end

   @implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 150)];
       blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       [self.view addSubview:blueView];
       [self addMovementGesturesToView:blueView];

       // UIImageView's and UILabel's don't have userInteractionEnabled by default!
       UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BombDodge.png"]]; // Any image in Xcode project
       imageView.center = CGPointMake(100, 250);
       [imageView sizeToFit];
       [self.view addSubview:imageView];
       [self addMovementGesturesToView:imageView];

       // Note: Changing the font size would be crisper than zooming a font!
       UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
       label.text = @"Hello Gestures!";
       label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
       label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       [label sizeToFit];
       label.center = CGPointMake(100, 400);
       [self.view addSubview:label];
       [self addMovementGesturesToView:label];
   }

   - (void)addMovementGesturesToView:(UIView *)view {
       view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;  // Enable user interaction

       UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
       panGesture.delegate = self;
       [view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

       UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];
       pinchGesture.delegate = self;
       [view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
   }
   ```
2. Implement gesture methods

   ```
   - (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture {
       CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:panGesture.view.superview];

       if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == panGesture.state ||UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == panGesture.state) {
           panGesture.view.center = CGPointMake(panGesture.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                                panGesture.view.center.y + translation.y);
           // Reset translation, so we can get translation delta's (i.e. change in translation)
           [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
       }
       // Don't need any logic for ended/failed/canceled states
   }

   - (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGesture {

       if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == pinchGesture.state ||
           UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == pinchGesture.state) {

           // Use the x or y scale, they should be the same for typical zooming (non-skewing)
           float currentScale = [[pinchGesture.view.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"] floatValue];

           // Variables to adjust the max/min values of zoom
           float minScale = 1.0;
           float maxScale = 2.0;
           float zoomSpeed = .5;

           float deltaScale = pinchGesture.scale;

           // You need to translate the zoom to 0 (origin) so that you
           // can multiply a speed factor and then translate back to "zoomSpace" around 1
           deltaScale = ((deltaScale - 1) * zoomSpeed) + 1;

           // Limit to min/max size (i.e maxScale = 2, current scale = 2, 2/2 = 1.0)
           //  A deltaScale is ~0.99 for decreasing or ~1.01 for increasing
           //  A deltaScale of 1.0 will maintain the zoom size
           deltaScale = MIN(deltaScale, maxScale / currentScale);
           deltaScale = MAX(deltaScale, minScale / currentScale);

           CGAffineTransform zoomTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinchGesture.view.transform, deltaScale, deltaScale);
           pinchGesture.view.transform = zoomTransform;

           // Reset to 1 for scale delta's
           //  Note: not 0, or we won't see a size: 0 * width = 0
           pinchGesture.scale = 1;
       }
   }

   - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
       return YES; // Works for most use cases of pinch + zoom + pan
   }
   ```

### Resources

- [Xcode Gesture Sample Project](https://github.com/PaulSolt/LimitPinchGestureZoom)
- [Apple's Gestures Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2)

Comment: This does not work unless simultaneous gesture recognition is allowed with gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method.

Comment: in handlePanGesture: the state is compared twice to UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged

Comment: many gestures will fire multiple times in the UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged. Read the guides on events for iOS: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541

Comment: the class reference is also packed with great information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood Klaas comment, in the if statement, the state was compared twice to UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged. I edited your answer to remove one of the comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested in a Swift implementation of this using Metal to do the rendering, I have a project available [here](https://github.com/TylerWhiteDesign/MetalPinch).

Comment: Hi tyler
It doesn't have pinch to rotate feature.

Answer (score 2):

### Swift

Many thanks a lot to Paul!!! Here is his Swift version:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var editorView: EditorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let blueView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
        view.addSubview(blueView)
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
        addMovementGesturesToView(blueView)
    }

    func addMovementGesturesToView(_ view: UIView) {
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        panGesture.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinchGesture(_:)))
        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    }

    @objc private func handlePanGesture(_ panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let panView = panGesture.view else { return }

        let translation = panGesture.translation(in: panView.superview)

        if panGesture.state == .began || panGesture.state == .changed {
            panGesture.view?.center = CGPoint(x: panView.center.x + translation.x, y: panView.center.y + translation.y)

            // Reset translation, so we can get translation delta's (i.e. change in translation)
            panGesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
        }
        // Don't need any logic for ended/failed/canceled states
    }

    @objc private func handlePinchGesture(_ pinchGesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let pinchView = pinchGesture.view else { return }

        if pinchGesture.state == .began || pinchGesture.state == .changed {
            let currentScale = scale(for: pinchView.transform)

            // Variables to adjust the max/min values of zoom
            let minScale: CGFloat = 0.2
            let maxScale: CGFloat = 3
            let zoomSpeed: CGFloat = 0.8

            var deltaScale = pinchGesture.scale

            // You need to translate the zoom to 0 (origin) so that you
            // can multiply a speed factor and then translate back to "zoomSpace" around 1
            deltaScale = ((deltaScale - 1) * zoomSpeed) + 1

            // Limit to min/max size (i.e maxScale = 2, current scale = 2, 2/2 = 1.0)
            //  A deltaScale is ~0.99 for decreasing or ~1.01 for increasing
            //  A deltaScale of 1.0 will maintain the zoom size
            deltaScale = min(deltaScale, maxScale / currentScale)
            deltaScale = max(deltaScale, minScale / currentScale)

            let zoomTransform = pinchView.transform.scaledBy(x: deltaScale, y: deltaScale)
            pinchView.transform = zoomTransform

            // Reset to 1 for scale delta's
            //  Note: not 0, or we won't see a size: 0 * width = 0
            pinchGesture.scale = 1
        }
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    private func scale(for transform: CGAffineTransform) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(CGFloat(transform.a * transform.a + transform.c * transform.c))
    }
}
```

### Demo (on Simulator):

[image]

Comment: OMG thanks I wasted way too many hours on this.