# Velocity issues in setTranslation:inView:

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I's using this method:

```
- (void)setTranslation:(CGPoint)translation inView:(UIView *)view
```

From `UIPanGestureRecognizer` class, and I don't understand the velocity discussions around that.

`Appel`'s documentation says:

> Sets the translation value in the coordinate system of the specified
>   view. Changing the translation value resets the velocity of the pan.

What's that exactly mean? What is "reset velocity of the pan"?

Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

--EDIT

See this code:

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.cardsScrollView];        

        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:recognizer.view];
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that if you're in the middle of the panning gesture (you're dragging something) and you call `setTranslation:inView:` on that gesture, it's velocity is going to be reset to 0;
A pan gesture not only gives you the translation but also the velocity of the gesture (how fast you're dragging) in units per second (points per second in this case). You can access the velocity by calling `velocityInView:`.
If you don't use the velocity then don't worry about it, otherwise keep the above in mind.

UPDATE:

I'm guessing you're trying to move the view as you drag it. I would do it slightly differently.

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    CGAffineTransform transform = recognizer.view.transform;
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(transform.tx, transform.ty) inView:self];
} else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.cardsScrollView];
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translation.x, translation.y);
}
```

The thing to keep in mind is that self.cardsScrollView should be the superview of the view you're trying to move.

Comment: But still, What's the mining of reset the velocity? I notice that if I don't use this method, the whole dragging go crazy.. :/

Comment: You mean that when you use `setTranslation:inView:` things go crazy? Hmm, maybe you can post a little bit more code, especially where you're setting the translation?

Comment: It's not just drag, It's drag and shrink together but just when the `UIView` changes to y direction (vertically).

Comment: Ok, well if that's the case then it depends how do you want to do the shrink eg. what's the connection between the translation and shrinking. But if you want to achieve "pinch" and "drag" at the same time, I suggest you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935539/can-uipinchgesturerecognizer-and-uipangesturerecognizer-be-merged

Comment: Anyway, your code above is make my `UIView` to "jump" when I drag at the second time :/

Comment: It's not a pinch Gesture, Simple as it's sounds, It's drag and shrink together. And the shrink factor is the distance from an anchor point.

Comment: I have updated the code to prevent the jump. As for the shrinking, it should be really simple to chain another `CGAffineTransformScale` transform to what I wrote up there. Take a look: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html